# Is it possible to migrate .env to GCP Secret Manager?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt.js application with firebase integration deployed on GKE in GCP. I use .env file with  firebase config. Is it possible to store these firebase config values in GCP Secret Manager and use these values during npm build?

Comment: You can store the file in Secret Manager, but you will have to download it before the npm build, do the build, and then delete the file. I don't think you can allow npm build process to download a file from secret manager with the correct credentials.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the env data to secret manager, but it's impossible to use values during npm build.

but you can use secret values in deployment manifest file, which is overriding your container env.

checkout the official documents below.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables

hope this works to you